# April answerathon competition

Tags: discussion, status-completed, unanswered-questions, fun, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on April 1st, UTC at Midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote for your answer.
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier)), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your 'day'.
- IF the question you answer is marked as a duplicate on the same 'day', your answer is invalidated.

Each 'day' will last for 24 hours from midnight UTC to midnight UTC.  So April 1st inclusive is a day.

Miss a day and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with a proper answer, ie with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

I'll provide the sample answer template below for  April 1st. If you intend to enter, put your name there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### April 8th - 1 participant left - Dorothy is out - JonathanReez wins

Answer (score 3):

### April 1st - 4 entrants so far

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) -
2. [JonathanReez](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90897/9009 - mts
3. [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90927/32134
4. [Dorothy -](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile)[Early morning car rental at Belfast Ferry Port?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88295/early-morning-car-rental-at-belfast-ferry-port/90930?noredirect=1#comment217617_90930) - mts
5. [Dorothy -](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) [How long does Turkish Airlines take for a flight refund?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90907/how-long-does-turkish-airlines-take-for-a-flight-refund/90920#90920)
6. [Dorothy -](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) [Amount required for full sponsoring for a member applying UK visitors visa for 20 days from India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90382/amount-required-for-full-sponsoring-for-a-member-applying-uk-visitors-visa-for-2/90917#90917)
7. [Dorothy -](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) [Schengen visa proof of accommodation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90515/schengen-visa-proof-of-accommodation/90916#90916)
8. [Dorothy -](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile)  [Why does the window-side armrest never move?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90401/why-does-the-window-side-armrest-never-move/90915#90915)

Answer (score 2):

### April 4th - 3 participants left

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JonathanReez](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) - [Can I have two types of German visa at the same time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91001/can-i-have-two-types-of-german-visa-at-the-same-time/91085#91085) - mts
2. [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91065/32134 - JonathanReez
3. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91134/9009 - JonathanReez

Answer (score 1):

### April 2nd - 3 participants left - Mark Mayo is out

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JonathanReez](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90961/9009 - mts
2. [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90947/32134 - JonathanReez
3. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90975/32134 - mts

Comment: gah, completely forgot about this while travelling back from New Zealand yesterday :(

Comment: I've taken the freedom to add the answer by Dorothy myself since she was active on that day. If anyone is to argue the regularity of that, go ahead and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

### April 3rd - 3 participants left

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JonathanReez](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91002/9009 - mts
2. [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90991/32134 - JonathanReez
3. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90983/32134 - mts

Answer (score 1):

### April 5th - 3 participants left

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JonathanReez](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91127/9009 - mts
2. [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts?tab=profile) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91137/32134 - JonathanReez
3. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) -  https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91134/32134 - mts

Answer (score 1):

### April 6th - 3 participants left

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JonathanReez](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91185/9009 - JonathanReez
2. [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts?tab=profile) -
3. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) - [Pet travel: France to the UK - Microchip/tattoo?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91086/pet-travel-france-to-the-uk-microchip-tattoo/91194#91194) - JonathanReez
4. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) - [Renew Schengen visa Issued from Greece without visiting the consulate in person?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91156/renew-schengen-visa-issued-from-greece-without-visiting-the-consulate-in-person/91198#91198) - JonathanReez
5. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) - 
   [Can I invite my parents to the UK while changing jobs (I'm on a work visa here)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90387/can-i-invite-my-parents-in-uk-while-changing-jobs-im-on-work-visa-here/91214#91214) - JonathanReez

Answer (score 1):

### April 7th - 2 participants left - mts is out

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JonathanReez](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91237/9009
2. [Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/dorothy?tab=profile) -

Comment: a pity I didn't make it. good luck to both of you!